# What are the models of distributed storage systems in the literature?

Tags: reference-request, distributed-systems

To understand the effectiveness and/or efficiency of a protocol implemented in distributed storage systems, it is often desirable to evaluate it in a quantitative way under a hypothetical model.

Obviously, every model is an approximation to the reality and there is not an all-purpose one. I expect to do a mini survey of the models of distributed storage systems in the literature. Specifically, I am interested in the models on *system throughput, read/write rate, read/write pattern, read/write duration (interval), read/write latency, communication delay, failure pattern, and more professional ones such as data consistency, quorum size, recovery mechanism, and so on*.

Therefore, I am requesting references, including but not limited to

1. statistical reports of commercial/open source distributed storage systems
2. hypothetical models used in research papers.
   a typical example: [costs and availability of replicated services](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~mukka/cs775s07/papers/availability.pdf)
    which studies availability, consistency, partition.
3. experimental results given in research papers, talks, and technical reports.
   typical examples: [Dynamo in Amazon [section 6]](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/amazon-dynamo-sosp2007.pdf) and [PNUTS in Yahoo! [section 5]](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~usriv/papers/pnuts.pdf%5d).
4. personal comments on such topics from blogs, non-research articles, and you.

Comment: Have you used [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.de/) before asking here? What did you find? Why were the results not satisfiable?

Comment: suggestion: look at NNTP and other P2P storage protocols. This is jut one family of storage systems. Maybe the web can be considered one too (NNTP existed before the web).

Comment: What about looking at the possibility or effectiveness of implementing a distributed storage protocol by means of another protocol. Just trying to get out of the more tedious approach.

Comment: @Raphael I have added some typical references. That are what I can found through Google. Generally, there cannot be a single standard by which we can determine whether some reference is satisfiable or not.

Comment: @babou P2P storage systems are worth studying. In particular, I prefer to storage systems using replication techniques. What are the typical P2P storage systems using replication? Furthermore, I am more interested in its measurements like *read/write rate, latency* mentioned in the post and their theoretical models. What are your recommendations for this? Thanks.

Comment: your topic is very open. l was only making a suggestion. what about distributed RAID systems for reliability and security?  ido not know it was ever used.